# How do you change NaNs to the closest number, either above or below

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation, nan

I have a 4x5 matrix, but I have some NaNs mixed in with the value. I really would like to change the NaNs to the nearest number, either above it or below it (because each column is disconnected to the next), like so:

```
A= NaN 10   35   150   1.5
   4.2 11   NaN  149   1.45
   4.8 NaN  36.1 153   1.3
   5.3 13   40   147   NaN
```

I would like to have a function that would change the matrix to:

```
B= 4.2 10   35   150   1.5
   4.2 11   35   149   1.45
   4.8 11   36.1 153   1.3
   5.3 13   40   147   1.3
```

I think I could use some sort of interpolation to do this, but Im not entirely sure how.

In this senario I am able to do it by hand but I will be using matrixes that are 1000sx1000s so couldn't do it then! I have looked for other examples of how to do this, but a lot of them change the NaNs to zeros.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Jordan

Comment: IMHO the most important question is:Why do you have NaNs at all ?

Answer (score 1):

use [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaintnans), a wonderful tool by John D'Errico that interpolate NaN elements in a 2-d array using non-NaN elements. It can also extrapolate, as it does not use a triangulation of the data. It offers several approaches to the interpolation, which give tradeoffs in accuracy versus speed and memory required.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this function does exactly what you are expecting, but it might be helpful:

```
knnimpute
```

As an example

```
A = [1 2 5;4 5 7;NaN -1 8;7 6 0]

A =

     1     2     5
     4     5     7
   NaN    -1     8
     7     6     0
```

you then call

```
knnimpute(A)
```

which yields

```
ans =

     1     2     5
     4     5     7
    -1    -1     8
     7     6     0
```